# How to upload and get image / formData with react native axios and multer

Tags: react-native, axios, multer

I try to post images to MongoDB but get status CODE 404,

- I have multer and static path '/uploads/' and this directory is on the frontend with some images, I get the array from the server but i dont know how to show them :
- i tried in flat list to show them like:

  <Image source={require("../../server/uploads/a3.jpg")} />//here its work.
  and when i replace to {require("../../server/**${item.imageurl}**" iI get error
- when i console log the require path I get the objects with url->> ../../server/uploads\a1.jpg
- see that the / is the opposite side \ , maybe its the problem?

---

now for upload I tried to :

1. I getting object(selectedImage) when I choosing file :

   ```
    "localUri": "file:/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FLior- 
    3698f362-fc81-4a77-8c97-8cd1349ce090/ImagePicker/d4c4b4ec-72e6-4e20-b6eb-4727bc84d93e.jpg",
   ```

and my axios post:

```
        if (selectedImage !== null) {
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("image", selectedImage);
        console.log(formData);
        try {
            const response = await indexApi.post(`/uploads`, formData);
            console.log("res", response);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("c", err);
        }
    }
};

the form data that i send look like:
    FormData {
  "_parts": Array [
    Array [
      "image",
      Object {
        "localUri": 
     "file:/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FLior-3698f362-fc81- 
     4a77-8c97-8cd1349ce090/ImagePicker/d4c4b4ec-72e6-4e20-b6eb-4727bc84d93e.jpg",
      },
    ],
  ],
}
```

and I get error 404, or 503.....

the backend parts:

1. image controller:

   ```
   const Image = require("../models/image");
   const _ = require("lodash");

    exports.getImages = (req, res) => {
   Image.find()
       .select("_id image desc")
       .then(images => {
           res.json({ images });
       })
       .catch(err => console.log("get images errors", err));
     };

    //INSERT NEW IMAGE//
      exports.uploadImage = (req, res) => {
       const image = new Image({
       image: req.file.path,
       desc: req.body.desc,
   });
   console.log(image);
   console.log(image);

   console.log("ss", image);
   image.save(err => {
       if (err) {
           return res.status(400).json({ error: "העלאת תמונה נכשלה" });
       }
       res.json({ message: "העלאת תמונה עברה בהצלחה" });
   });
   ```

   };
2. image route:

   ```
   const express = require("express");
    const { getImages, uploadImage } = require("../controllers/image");
   const multer = require("multer");

   //configure the images
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
     destination: function (req, file, cb) {
       cb(null, "./uploads");
     },
      filename: function (req, file, cb) {
       console.log("f", file);
       cb(null, file.originalname);
     },
     });

    const upload = multer({
   storage: storage,
   limits: {
       fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 55,
   },
   });

   const router = express.Router();
   router.get("/images", getImages);
   router.post("/images/new", upload.single("image"), uploadImage);
   module.exports = router;
   ```

**so maybe my prolbem go from the route... beacuse i dont understand the that thing that i have one route (uploads) for the images, and another route with get and post method(/images) and for post (/images/new)**

Edit. Error Picture for the first part
[image]

Comment: can you list your `value` from **1**: `image` (**get from db**) and **2**: `item.imageUrl` (**in your view**)

Comment: i get from database:::::
s Object {
  "images": Array [
    Object {
      "_id": "5fc4023a907284016211ed4f",
      "desc": "1",
      "imageurl": "uploads\\a1.jpg",
    },

    Object {
      "_id": "5fc40255907284016211ed52",
      "desc": "4",
      "imageurl": "uploads\\a4.jpg",
  
    },
  ],
}

---------------------
and for example :

console.log(`../../server/${item.imageurl}`)
--->../../server/uploads\f3.jpg

Comment: the **double backslashes** after **upload** - `uploads\\a1.jpg` is that **intentional**?

Comment: no, and also the / is opposite like u see (its \ )
but i dont no when it came from

Comment: i defined regular destination like so:
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
 destination: function (req, file, cb) {
  cb(null, "./uploads");
 },

and in the index
app.use("/uploads", express.static("uploads"));

Comment: could you try `cb(null, "/uploads");` without the **period** sign and see if anything change?

Comment: this what i have now :  "imageurl": "\\uploads\\k2.jpg",

Comment: and my error is (like before):
syntax error invalid call require (../../server/+item.imageurl)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225300/discussion-between-roei-grinshpan-and-lala).

Comment: I just provide a potential solution. Try that first

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing this first:-

**a**. Your `require` might not able to read the incoming `value` from `item.imageUrl` since you called it inside **double quotes** (`""`):-

- try using **backticks** (``):-

```html
<Image source={require(`../../server/${item.imageUrl}`)} />
```

#### OR

You could try one of these **two** ways:-

1. saving **image** `path` in `db`

- in `imageUpload` method/function:-

```js
//INSERT NEW IMAGE//
exports.uploadImage = (req, res) => {
  const image = new Image({
    // don't do this
    // image: req.file.path,
    // instead try do this
    image: '/uploads/' + req.file.originalname, 
    desc: req.body.desc,
  });
  console.log(image);
  console.log(image);

  console.log("ss", image);
  image.save(err => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "העלאת תמונה נכשלה" });
    }
    res.json({ message: "העלאת תמונה עברה בהצלחה" });
  });
```

1. saving **image** `originalname` **only** in `db`

- in `imageUpload` method/function:-

```js
//INSERT NEW IMAGE//
exports.uploadImage = (req, res) => {
  const image = new Image({
    // don't do this
    // image: req.file.path,
    // instead try do this
    image: req.file.originalname, 
    desc: req.body.desc,
  });
  console.log(image);
  console.log(image);

  console.log("ss", image);
  image.save(err => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "העלאת תמונה נכשלה" });
    }
    res.json({ message: "העלאת תמונה עברה בהצלחה" });
  });
```

- in 'view' or **front-end**:-

```html
<Image source={require(`../../server/uploads/${item.imageUrl}`)} />
```

Comment: sorry, its doesnt help me.

i did other thing, now i get image url like i need ("imageurl": "uploads/k2.jpg")

after i put this -  > image: req.file.path.replace(/\\/g, "/"),
i replaced replaced the path a littlte bit,
so now i have exactly path "uploads/k2.jpg"

but the problem stay the same "syntax error "......

and i tried both with backtick `` and " " + image.imageurl.

Comment: when i try  uri: "http://localhost:8080/uploads/k2.jpg" 
its dont show the image

Comment: I don't have much experience with `react-native`. I think you should open new `question` focusing on :- **Topic: Getting syntax error displaying image** and show these **two** lines of code you've tried:- **1st**: `<Image source={require("../../server/uploads/" + item.imageUrl)} />` (**image won't show up & get syntax error**). **2**: `<Image source={require("../../server/uploads/k2.jpg")} />` (**image successfully show up**). You might be able to get some help then.

Comment: Since you already tried changing your `path` from `uploads\\k2.jpg` to `uploads/k2.jpg`. Made me realised that your `path` might **works** just fine.